# Books about penalized regression

Tags: regression, references, model-selection, regularization

I'm looking for textbooks that discuss penalized regression in a methodical manner and present various model selection methods, such as AIC, BIC, Cp as special cases of penalized regression. The textbooks i am looking for don't have to be dedicated to penalized regression, rather this subject can be discussed in a chapter or a section of a more general book. An example of the kind of discussion that I am looking for can be seen in [these](http://math.ucsd.edu/~eariasca/math282b/penalized-regression.pdf) slides by UCSD instructor Ery Arias-Castro. Books can be in English, French or German. Thanks.

Comment: is there a problem with [ESL2](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)?

Answer (score 3):

The Elements of Statistical Learning.

Free online.

http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend P.J. Green and B.W. Silverman - "Nonparametric regression and generalised linear models - a roughness penalty approach", CHapman & Hall/CRC Monographs on statistics and applied probability, volume 58.