# Penalized methods comprehensive overview

Tags: regression, references, lasso, regularization

For the last 10 years from 2004 we have seen a growth in the number of different regularization techniques that have been in use. First it was LASSO, then Adaptive-LASSO, Elastic Net, SCAD, MC+, just to name a few. Is there any definitive book chapter or paper which provides a comprehensive overview of ALL the different penalized methods (Convex, Non-Convex, Bayesian, Frequentist etc)(LASSO and all its modern rivals :-) ) and kind of tells us why one method is better/more useful than the other both theoretically and in any applied  setting?

Comment: There is some coverage in the well known ["Elements of Statistcal Learning"](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print10.pdf) textbook (need to wait a little until the whole pdf loads), but perhaps it is too basic and does not cover the newest techniques.

Comment: for those of who you are interested this book here answers my question to a large extent , 

Statistical Learning with Sparsity : The Lasso and Generalizations

Statistical Learning with Sparsity : The Lasso and Generalizations
Author: Hastie, Trevor, Tibshirani, Robert, Wainwright, Martin

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77612/books-about-penalized-regression